# Ruby REGEX parser

Tags: ruby, regex

Can someone have a look at the below code and tell me whether this is truly the correct way to go about parsing text after the ":" sign.

```
require 'yaml'

the_file = ARGV[0]
f =  File.open(the_file)
content = f.read
r = Regexp.new(/((?=:).+)/)
emails = content.scan(r).uniq
puts YAML.dump(emails)
```

This script parses email addresses from text files to clean out junk. TEXT:email_address.

I'm trying to make my scripts a bit more efficient. So all my ruby/regex scripts look the same, only with different regex patterns. I wrote them in ruby by cutting an dpasting here and there, and because I have ruby on the majority of my servers, so it's easier to run any script anywhere.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you truly just want text after the first `:`, I would not use a Regex. I would use [String#split](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-split)

```
lines = File.readlines(the_file)
emails = lines.map { |line| line.split(':', 2).last }.uniq
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want valid emails, I would just search for a regexp that captures emails:

```
email_regexp = /[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}/
puts YAML.dump(
  File.read(ARGV[0]).scan(email_regexp)
)
```

Comment: TLDs may have much more than 6 character length, see: http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Comment: This regex produces a lot of false negative, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses

Answer (score 0):

If you know the colon is the left delimiter before the email, and a close paren on the right, then you can just use

```
:(.+[^)])
```

as your regex to extract whatever is in between. There are some very specific email-matching regexen out there though, which may be more appropriate (for when the source text is less 'regular')